# how to pass array of joins to select query in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from multiple tables. I have stored join statements in a $Joins array and passed that array to model
Here is what I tried so far -

```
$tbl_name="user_master";
$select= ['user_master.*', 'country.country_name', 'city.city_name', 'login_master.email_id', 'login_master.password'];
$joins=[
         "'country', 'user_master.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id'",
         "'city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id'",
         "'login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 'login_master.user_id'"
       ]; 
$users=$obj->getdata($tbl_name,$select,$joins);
```

Model -

```
public function getdata($tbl_name,$select,$joins)
    {
        $users = DB::table($tbl_name)
                ->join($joins)
                ->select($select)
                ->paginate(5);

                return $users;
    }
```

I am trying to pass $joins array to query but it showing error -
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join(), called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo_laravel/app/Models/Userdata.php on line 61 and defined

If I try as -

```
$users = DB::table($tbl_name)
                ->join('country', 'user_master.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id')
                ->join('city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id')
                ->join('login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 'login_master.user_id')
                ->select($select)
                ->paginate(5);

                return $users;
```

It is working fine but when I pass array to joins it shows error.
How to solve it?
Please help me.

Comment: i think join will not accept the array parameter . use your second example .it's clear .

Comment: Join can accept array but don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$joins` in this format:

```
$joins = [
    ['country', 'user_master.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id'],
    ['city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id'],
    ['login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 'login_master.user_id'],
];
```

and model:

```
public function getdata($tbl_name, $select, $joins)
{
    $users = DB::table($tbl_name);

    foreach ($joins as $join) {
        $users = $users->join(...$join);
    }

    $users = $users
        ->select($select)
        ->paginate(5);

    return $users;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not working. Getting a same error.