# Error In LEFT JOIN CODELGNITER "Not unique table/alias"

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I've a got a error says **`Not unique table/alias: 'pcdom_missionaries'`**

here's my sample code in model

```
public function samplemethodname()
    {
        $this->db->select('companionship_id, missionary_one_id, missionary_two_id, missionary_three_id, pcdom_companionship.zone_id AS pczone_id, pcdom_companionship.district_id AS pcdistrict_id,
            pcdom_companionship.area_id AS pcarea_id, assignment, zone_name, pcdom_zone.zone_id AS pz_zone_id, district_name, pcdom_district.district_id AS pd_district_id, area_name, pcdom_area.area_id AS pa_area_id, missionary_id, missionaries_name')
                ->from('pcdom_companionship')
                ->join('pcdom_missionaries','pcdom_missionaries.missionary_id = pcdom_companionship.missionary_one_id','left')
                ->join('pcdom_missionaries','pcdom_missionaries.missionary_id = pcdom_companionship.missionary_two_id','left')
                ->join('pcdom_missionaries','pcdom_missionaries.missionary_id = pcdom_companionship.missionary_three_id','left')
                ->join('pcdom_zone','pcdom_zone.zone_id = pcdom_companionship.zone_id','left')
                ->join('pcdom_district','pcdom_district.district_id = pcdom_companionship.district_id','left')
                ->join('pcdom_area','pcdom_area.area_id = pcdom_companionship.area_id','left');
                $sql = $this->db->get();
                if($sql && $sql->num_rows() > 0 )
                    return $sql->result();
                else
                    return;
    }
```

An error appears in the image

[image: Not unique table/alias: 'pcdom_missionaries']

Can Anyone had the ideas?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing self joins on `pcdom_missionaries` you need to alias `pcdom_missionaries` table in each separate joins to make it look unique to SQL so it can use it in joins without confusion

```
->join('pcdom_missionaries as pcdom_m1','pcdom_m1.missionary_id = pcdom_companionship.missionary_one_id','left')
->join('pcdom_missionaries as pcdom_m2','pcdom_m2.missionary_id = pcdom_companionship.missionary_two_id','left')
->join('pcdom_missionaries as pcdom_m3','pcdom_m3.missionary_id = pcdom_companionship.missionary_three_id','left')
```

Comment: can i put an array inside the join?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get , you mean array as join condition? or you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603992/how-to-pass-array-of-joins-to-select-query-in-laravel-5-2)?

Comment: yes thats it.. array inside join condition.. well you answer my questions .. thanks